# When non-const members can be used in constexpr member functions?

Tags: c++, class, static, constexpr

I encountered a situation I don't understand. Would somebody be so nice to explain why first code compiles correctly while second gives an error:

> error: the value of 'TestClass::z' is not usable in a constant expression
>     static constexpr int sum() {return x+y+z;}
>     ----------------------------------------------------^
>   note: 'int TestClass::z' is not const
>     static int z;"

Working code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class TestClass
{
    public:
        constexpr int sum() {return x+y+z;}

    private:
        static constexpr int x = 2;
        static const int y = 3;
        int z = 5;

};

int main()
{
    TestClass tc;
    cout << tc.sum() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

But when I try to make `TestClass::sum()` static I get aforementioned error:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class TestClass
{
    public:
        static constexpr int sum() {return x+y+z;}

    private:
        static constexpr int x = 2;
        static const int y = 3;
        static int z;

};

int TestClass::z = 5;

int main()
{
    TestClass tc;
    cout << tc.sum() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

P.S. I'm using mingw32-g++ 4.8.1

Comment: `constexpr` member functions are [even allowed to change data members](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/039aab4e6feb3ed1) if Clang is to be believed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case, the result depends only on the function's arguments, including the implicit `this` used to access `z`. This doesn't disqualify it from being `constexpr` - if all the arguments are constant expressions, then so is the result.

In your example, it isn't a constant expression (since `tc` isn't), but that doesn't matter since it's not being used in a context that requires one. Here's an example showing its use in a constant expression:

```
constexpr TestClass tc;
array<int, tc.sum()> a;
cout << a.size() << endl;
```

In the second case, the result also depends on a static variable, whose value could change during the program. This does disqualify it - even if all the arguments are constant expressions, `z` isn't, and so the result of a function call can never be a constant expression.

Comment: Hmm... But if I understand it correctly in both cases `sum()` uses member which could be changed during program execution. Shouldn't it in both cases do the same: "ignore" constexpr?

Comment: @Lehu: In the first case, it's only a constant expression if the `TestClass` object is constant, so that the member variable can't change. So `constexpr` is allowed, with the usual meaning of "yielding a constant expression if all arguments are constant expressions". In the second case, it can never be a constant expression, so `constexpr` isn't allowed.